# Thread and init at the same time (how it works?)

Tags: python, multithreading, constructor, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I recently started to study threads and I know it is about multiple processing stuff I just don't get why this is happening

```
import threading

class BuckyMessenger(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("test")

    def run(self):
        for _ in range(4):
            print(threading.current_thread().getName())

    x = BuckyMessenger(name='Send')
y = BuckyMessenger(name='Receive')
z = BuckyMessenger(name='Nothing')
x.start()
y.start()
z.start()
```

**I Expected this to happen:**

```
test
Send
test
Receive
test
Nothing
```

from here on, I should have gotten 9 more prints of 3 random "Send" and 3 random "Receive" and 3  Random "Nothing", like the following: (rest of the  results)

```
Send
Receive 
Nothing 
Nothing
Nothing
Send
Receive 
Receive 
send
```

**But this is the result I got:**
I  mean why? why python acts this way?

```
test
test
test
Thread-1
Thread-1
Thread-1
Thread-1
Thread-2
Thread-2
Thread-2
Thread-2
Thread-3
Thread-3
Thread-3
Thread-3
```

Comment: probably because the time to initialize the thread took just as long to print the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the current thread running and set its name. Then you can use that reference to print its name. Notice the changes in constructor and `run` method. As for the effect of serial execution, is due to the ability of each thread to be executed fast enough and finish before another takes place, because of the small amount of loop cycles:

```
import threading

class BuckyMessenger(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        print("test")

    def run(self):
        curThread = threading.current_thread()
        curThread.name = self.name
        for _ in range(4):
            print(curThread.name)

x = BuckyMessenger(name='Send')
y = BuckyMessenger(name='Receive')
z = BuckyMessenger(name='Nothing')
x.start()
y.start()
z.start()
```

Possible Output:

```
test
test
test
Send
Send
Send
Send
Receive
Nothing
Nothing
Receive
Nothing
Nothing
Receive
Receive
```

Comment: test
test
test
Send
Send
Send
Send
Receive
Receive
Receive
Receive
Nothing
Nothing
Nothing
Nothing, that's the result every time , is it threading? since I'm not getting a mixed of "Receive" and "Nothing" and "Send"

Comment: It's because of the ability of CPU to execute each thread quick enough so it looks like serial execution. One thing you can do is to increase the number of loop cycles and another is to force each thread to suspend for a randomly generated amount of time e.g. `time.sleep(random.random())`. Make sure to import the `time` and `random` modules for the latter option. Place `time.sleep(random.random())` in the `for` loop, before the `print` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your initializer does not set the passed `name` to the `BuckyMessanger`. This is because you override the original `Thread.__init__()`, which handles `name` as you would expect. The default names for the threads are `Thread-1` and so on, in the respective order they are created. Change your initializer to something like the following to override the defaults:

```
def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        print("test")
```

As for why they are printed in that order, `BuckyMessanger.run()` runs after each `start()` and finishes before the next `start()` is called.